# Usando REST do Paypal com ASP Clássico

Tags: rest, asp

Estou tentando efetuar uma chamada simples à API do Paypal com o seguinte código:

```
On error resume next

Set objHTTP = CreateObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP")
objHTTP.open "POST", "https://api.sandbox.paypal.com/v1/oauth2/token", False

objHTTP.setRequestHeader "Accept", "application/json"
objHTTP.setRequestHeader "Accept-Language", "en_US"
objHTTP.setRequestHeader "Authorization", "Basic " & Base64Encode("client-id:secret")
objHTTP.send "grant_type=client_credentials"

Response.Write err.description & " | " & err.number
```

Mas está retornando o erro:

```
The download of the specified resource has failed
```

Com o Postman funciona sem problemas. Alguém saberia dizer onde está o erro? Estou utilizando em localhost sem SSL (não sei se isso afeta).